# What to record in Dubai?

Tags: field-recording, portable-recorder, pcm-d50, sony-pcm-d50

I'm visiting Dubai for a vacation next week and want to also do a little field recording. Has anyone any suggestions of good places to record, interesting markets etc. I'm intending to go to the top of the Burj Kalifah (tallest building on earth) and hope to record something up there, don't know if there will be any thing but there might be some interesting sounds at 700m!!
Would be great to hear of any suggestions?

I'm just taking my D50 as don't want to take too much equipment.

Answer (score 4):

The monorail/transit system is widely underused, and could help you collect some clean transit sounds. The gold or spice souqs aren't bad to visit for general outdoor crowd ambiences, but I don't remember when they're busiest. The spice souq is also right by a canal/river, usually with some decent activity (boats, people loading/unloading gear, and call to prayers that happen at multiple nearby mosques that create an interesting ambience all their own). Plenty of beaches to collect surf sounds as well. You may also want to look into if there are any horse races going on while you're there...interesting sounds from the spectators' perspective.

Comment: Yes please do record the Metro The Dubai Metro is the almost the same type of vehicles and track as used in Sydney, Vancouver and Singapore...except, as Shaun mentioned, nearly empty.
Will swop you some of these sounds here- http://www.kurthuman.com/Listen-Field-Recording for some those you record in Dubai

Answer (score 0):

Hey nice to know your heading where I lived my whole life (It sucks though you'll see..). If your out for crowds you can check out Karama Near The Fish Market or a huge shopping mall called Dragon Mart, I haven't been to these places in a while but when I used to it was almost always crowded in the evenings. Be sure to get some stuff specific to Dubai like in the Metro (You can't chew gum or fall asleep in there, it's stupid but trust me my brother almost got in trouble for dosing off one time.) If your going to be heading to the Burj Khalifa* you should also check out some fountain show the mall beside it called Dubai Mall has. It's similar to the thing in Vegas (It's made by the same people apparently), you can get more crowds there, but I'm not quite sure about the timings. If you go on a desert safari which I'd recommend it's really fun, if you stay till the evening they have belly dancers and middle eastern music performances, ask them if their live players just to be sure. Anyway have fun, hope this isn't a messy post I'm just spitting out ideas off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Stephen. Why do you say it sucks?

Comment: I guess it's an okay place to visit but living there is really boring you'll see its nothing but shopping stuff really..

Answer (score 0):

I've now added some sounds I recorded to my SoundCloud account:
[Sounds from Dubai - April 2012](http://snd.sc/IEyVZh)